# Поиск по тегу OvalShape

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть на форме множество `OvalShape`, и у каждого свой тег. 
При выполнении программы нужно изменить цвет определенного `ovalShape`. Как найти нужный по тегу?

Comment: Какой фреймворк? C# сам по себе не умеет рисовать.

Comment: using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks; 
Visual Basic PowerPack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection(v=vs.80).aspx) и, как самое удобное в данном случае, [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var yourShape = this.Controls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tag == "ваш_тег");
```